# Is there a way in flutter to switch the screen off when i click a button?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create an app launcher with flutter but failing to implement the functionality of turning screen of on double tap.

is there any package that can help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter app - ability to turn off the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889443/flutter-app-ability-to-turn-off-the-screen)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the flutter_app_lock package but what I'd recommend using platform specific methods to send your request from your flutter app to the system platform.

And if you want there's a package for sending requests too. The package is called Pigeon and you can find more about sending requests to android or swift in this link: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-swift-tab