# Is it possible to create a flutter app to lock screen/ Turn on and off the screen in 2022?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-lockscreenwidget

flutter native dependencies

I need a way to access native dependencies

Comment: check this please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889443/flutter-app-ability-to-turn-off-the-screen

Comment: To turn on/off screen depending on years, you first must check what year it is and then execute function depending on that condition

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [flutter_screen_lock](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screen_lock), which provides the ability to lock the screen on ios and android. Biometric authentication can be used in addition to passcode.